# Baked shadows look different when camera post-processing is on/off

Tags: unity, lightmap

Sooo... basically title. I have no idea what's going on here. I don't think I've seen this kind of behavior before, or perhaps I did but I can't remember it. Any idea on what's happening here? Couldn't find anything about it.

[image: Post-processing OFF]

*Postprocessing OFF*

[image: Post-processing ON]

*Postprocessing ON*

Not like it's causing any issue, it just kinda bothers me lol. I'm using Unity 2022.3.5 with URP 14.0.8, on Windows 11 with an Intel i3 11th. This is on the editor, not sure if it happens as well on builds.

UPDATE: Something I forgot to mention, there's no post processing volume on the scene.

Comment: This looks like banding, which can occur if your image is being written to a low bit depth buffer, then colour corrected/tonemapped or otherwise re-processed and re-saved into another low bit depth buffer. Each step discards low bits from the colour that won't fit in the destination, so two very similar greys can get rounded to the same colour, causing these distinct plateaus in otherwise smooth gradients. Take a look for any options that let you output or do intermediate rendering in a higher bit depth, like a high dynamic range (HDR) format

Comment: If HDR/higher bit depths are impractical for performance or device support on your target hardware, then the best thing you can do is add noise dithering to break up the bands. [This GDC talk on the rendering of Inside shows the issue and how they used dithering (combined with temporal antialiasing) to combat it](https://gdcvault.com/play/1023304/Low-Complexity-High-Fidelity-INSIDE)

Comment: @DMGregory It was indeed something related to that. Just changing an enum from low to high in one of the URP S.O. settings did it. I can't remember what exactly was and I'm not in my PC right now but once I'll get back to it, I'll explain it more in detail as an answer. Thanks again!